# Is it possible to have more then one version of php in xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

for example some of my project are running on php 7.4 but when i want to install magento it require 7.3[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can install multiple xampp version then you can start php version you need.

[image]

then you can start any version you want, you can't run both of multiple version at same time you have to enable only one version.